# Way of calculating $\pi$ with a spiral?

Tags: geometry

Is there a way of calculating the digits of $\pi$ in your head, using only your head, from scratch, kind of like the *ancients* did, but which also somehow involves a spiral or a helix? This may be a weird question, in which case I would appreciate you informing me of it's weirdness so that I make take appropriate action.

Comment: What led you to ask this question? Specifically, why do you suspect that there is a method that involves a spiral or helix?

Comment: Perhaps inspired by the Mathematicum in Gießen, Germany? http://www.planet-wissen.de/alltag_gesundheit/lernen/mathematik/img/tempx_mathematik_pi_g.jpg In my opinion this has nothing to do with mathematics at all, and in fact I fear that this is one of the many examples where a misleading public image of mathematics is created (collecting digits?!). You learn absolutely nothing about the meaing of $\pi$ by looking at hundreds of digits. For those interested in the computation of $\pi$, try to understand the quite recent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: @Stahl I'm pulling this out of my a**. Besides that there is absolutely no intuition behind this. It's simply a question about, is is possible that there is a connection between two random ideas pulled out of my arse? That of the helix/spiral and that of pinning down the digits of the famous constant $\pi$?

Comment: I don't know about any spiral, but [here](http://itech.fgcu.edu/faculty/clindsey/mhf4404/archimedes/archimedes.html) is an article on how archimedes calculated $\pi$.